# Spring and Hibernate: can I get rid of hibernate.cfg.xml and rely on annotation alone?

Tags: hibernate, spring

I am using spring and hibernate together. In my application context, I have this section:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration
            </value>
        </property>
```

The hibernate.cfg.xml only contains a list of classes we want hibernate to manage persistence.

I wonder if I can replace this file totally? Can we simply rely on annotation alone to discover the list of classes that needs ORM?

If it is possible in spring, then how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With **[AnnotationSessionFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html)**

**For example**

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="namingStrategy">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <!-- Hibernate configurations -->
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect"><!-- dialect --></prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"><!-- use_second_level_cache --></prop>
            <!-- and so on -->
        </props>
    </property>

    <!-- Package to scan for entity classes -->
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.domain" />

    <!-- OR -->
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.domain1</value>
            <value>com.domain2</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <!-- OR -->     
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.domain.Entity1</value>
            <value>com.domain.Entity2</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: @Ischin: Thanks for the answer. I used the AnnotationSessionFactoryBean, and I got these error message: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [MyApp.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'packagesToScan' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean]: No property 'packagesToScan' found

Comment: I am using these packages: org.hibernate hibernate-core/hibernate-annotations 3.3.1.GA; javax.persistence persistence-api 1.0 and spring version 2.5.5

Comment: Just found out why: the property only exists in spring version 2.5.6 or higher